# Bad hard drive recovery, odd drive recognition issue

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I have a 1GB hard drive that's decided to die on me.  Nothing unusual there.

However, when I hook it up via, say, USB dock it shows up in fdisk along with the correct partition table for a minute... then vanishes?  If I start ddrescue up immediately after connecting it, it'll sit for a minute or two and then say the input file has disappeared.

Any ideas on how I can force this puppy to stay available to the system while I rip a bit by bit copy?

Comment: There isn't a way to force the HDD to stay online sounds like HDD has seen better days.  The only way I know would require using a data recovery service, which would transplant the platters in a clean-room, the problem isn't solvable by you directly.

Comment: Yah, that's kind of what I am afraid of :P  I've heard some people have success with transplanting a controller, but it's kind of old so finding a dupe would be a pain.

Comment: I've never seen a situation where it comes up but won't stay up before, tho... hence the question.

Comment: I have.  There is even a nearly identical question by somebody else that was ask recently.  As I said, the problem isn't something you can solve, since its likely at the mechanical level.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned hooking it up via USB so I'm assuming this is an external drive.  When this happens it usually means that whatever piece is between the SATA drive and usb output is faulty. The good news is if you can see the correct partition table briefly then there's a good chance your data is in tact and the MBR is fine as well.

The best thing to do would be to crack open your drive (you will most likely ruin the plastic), take out the actual HD and hook it up directly into a PC.

If you don't have access to a PC you can buy a SATA to USB external enclosure like [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817392032). If you scroll down in the description for that link you can see a picture with the hard drive sticking out of the case and a small circuit board connecting the SATA input to USB out.  That is most likely what is wrong with your drive.

Be careful about plugging the drive in in it's current state and attempting to get files off quickly.  Trying to write from your HD to the computer and then having the connection cut out is a great way to corrupt the MBR.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid you missed some details.  It's not an external drive, it's a regular SATA HD.  As I mentioned, I've already tried using a USB dock (two, in fact) with no luck - the OS recognized the HD for a minute, then suddenly disappears it.